# Longest Common Prefixes

Tags: algorithm, suffix-array

Suppose I constructed a suffix array, i.e. an array of integers giving the starting positions of all suffixes of a string in lexicographical order.

Example: For a string `str=abcabbca`,

the suffix array is:

```
suffixArray[] = [7 3 0 4 5 1 6 2]
```

---

Explanation:

```
i   Suffix      LCP of str and str[i..]   Length of LCP
7   a           a                           1
3   abbca       ab                          2
0   abcabbca    abcabbca                    8
4   bbca        empty string                0
5   bca         empty string                0
1   bcabbca     empty string                0
6   ca          empty string                0
2   cabbca      empty string                0
```

---

Now with this `suffixArray` constructed, I want to find the **length of the Longest Common Prefix (LCP)** between `str` (the string itself) and *each of the other suffixes*. What is the most **efficient way** to do it?

Comment: Can we assume that you also constructed the _standard LCP array_, i.e. the array such that LCP[i] = the longest common prefix of SA[i] and SA[-1]? It is often constructed as part of the suffix array construction.

Comment: Yup exactly i had constructed  the standard LCP array.

Comment: An easy solution https://youtu.be/f-JiELCbkOs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, I'll assume we have access to the suffix array `SA` as well as the standard `LCP` array, i.e. a data structure that tells us, at index i>0, what the length of the longest common prefix of suffix `SA[i]` and its lexicographic predecessor `SA[i-1]` is.

I'll use the letter L to refer to the special LCP array we want to construct, as described in the question. I'll use the letter N to refer to the length of the input string `str`.

Then what we can do is this:

1. Determine the position of `str` within the suffix array. We can do this by screening `SA` linearly to find the entry `0`. (Explanation: `str` is the suffix of `str` starting at position 0. Therefore, `0` must appear as an entry of the suffix array.)
2. Suppose the entry we find is at index k. Then we can set `L[k]:=N`, we because `SA[k]` is the string itself and has a prefix of N characters in common with itself.
3. Then we can set `L[k-1]:=LCP[k]` and `L[k+1]:=LCP[k+1]` because that is how the standard LCP is defined.
4. Then we go backwards from i:=k-2 down to 0 and set

   ```
   L[i] := min(LCP[i+1],L[i+1])
   ```

   This works because, at each iteration i, `LCP[i+1]` tells us the longest common prefix of the adjacent suffixes `SA[i]` and `SA[i+1]`, and `L[i+1]` tells us the longest common prefix of the previously processed suffix `SA[i+1]` and the input string `str`. `L[i]` must be the minimum of those two, because `L[i]` indicates how long a prefix `SA[i]` has in common with `str`, and that cannot be longer than the prefix it has in common with `SA[i+1]`, otherwise its position in the suffix array would be closer to k.
5. We also count forward from i:=k+2 to N and set

   ```
   L[i] := min(LCP[i],L[i-1])
   ```

   based on the same reasoning.

Then all N values of `L` have been set, and it took no more than O(N) time, assuming that random access to the arrays and integer comparison are O(1), respectively.

Since the array we compute is N entries in length, a complexity of O(N) is optimal.

*(Note. You can start the loops in steps 4 and 5 at k-1 and k+1, respectively, and get rid of step 3. The extra step only serves to make the explanation -- hopefully -- a little easier to follow.)*

Comment: :Thanks a lot ,that is exactly what i wanted .. :)